# Linear categories in Lawvere's Conceptual Mathematics

Tags: category-theory

In Lawvere's Conceptual Mathematics, linear categories (apparently called additive categories elsewhere) are defined as seen in this paragraph:

[Linear category definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bAL7.png)

Lawvere proceeds to define a 'product' of two matrices in a linear category as follows:

[Matrix product definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsPCc.png)

And then makes the following claim:

[Map identity with f,g and h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rHfj.png)

I've tried in vain to prove Lawvere's claim (following his definitions) that the product of these two matrices must indeed have the form that he stated, with the first row being $1,h$ and the second row being $0,1$. No additional explanation is provided in the text.

Why must this be true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product $X\times Y$ implicitly comes with two fixed projections $\pi_X,\pi_Y$, and these play an implicit role in the definitions.
 
Dually, the coproduct $X+Y$ comes equipped with inclusions $\iota_X,\iota_Y$.

First, observe that (writing composition *to the right*), 
$$\underset{X+Y\,\to\, X\times Y\,\to\, X}{\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pi_X}\ =\ \pmatrix{a\\c}$$
and similarly, composing it by $\pi_Y$ yields the second column. 
Consequently, as $1_{X\times Y}=\alpha\,\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, we have 
$$ \pi_X\ =\ \alpha\,\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\pi_X\ =\underset{X\times Y\to X+Y\to X}{\qquad \alpha\,\pmatrix{1\\0}}\,. $$
Dual statements hold for rows and the $\iota$'s.

From here, we can evaluate the 3 required elements like:
$$\iota_Y\cdot\,\pmatrix{1&f\\0&1}\alpha\pmatrix{1&g\\0&1}\,\cdot\pi_X\ =\ 
\pmatrix{0&1}\,\alpha\,\pmatrix{1\\0}\ =\ \pmatrix{0&1}\pi_X\ =\ 0\,.$$

Comment: I can follow your reasoning, but I am curious if you can generalize this to show that $\pmatrix{a&b}\alpha \pmatrix{x\\y}$ is $ax+by$ or something of the sort? (Defining $h = f + g$ in the example above).

Comment: Yes, once distributivity over composition is proved. Check that we have $(a, b) =(a, 0)+(0,b)$ according to the definition, and then $$\pmatrix{a&b}\pmatrix{c\\d} =\pmatrix{a&0}\pmatrix{c\\d} +\pmatrix{0 & b}\pmatrix{c\\d} =ac+bd$$

Comment: I suppose I'm being dull here but I don't see how either of these statements are true... starting with $(a,0)+(0,b)$, presumably I want to look at its projections to show that they coincide with $(a,b)$'s, but I can't go from the definition of addition to understand how you can calculate the projections.

I hope it's okay that I'm taking this beyond the scope of the original question--I'm struggling to get an intuition for these things.

Comment: I can compute $\pmatrix{1&(0,b)\\0&1} \pi_Y = \pmatrix{b \\ \pi_Y}$ but I don't know how to cancel out the $\alpha$ in the multiplication.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe the easiest way would be, if we could already fix all the $\pi_X,\pi_Y$ and $\iota_X,\iota_Y$ so that $\pmatrix{1_X&0\\0&1_Y}$ - hence $\alpha$ also - eventually becomes the identity. Fix, say, the projections arbitrarily. Then, as $X\times Y\cong X+Y$, the object $X\times Y$ itself can serve as the coproduct. (Basically we put the $\alpha$'s in the inclusions $\iota_X,\iota_Y$.)

Comment: More specifically, once all projections are fixed, *define* $X+Y:=X\times Y$ with the inclusions $(1_X,0):X\to X\times Y$ and $(0,1_Y):Y\to X\times Y$. Based on the answer's statements, this is going to be a coproduct diagram under the given hypothesis. Once these are fixed for all object pairs, $\alpha$ will become the identity.

Comment: I don't know if this actually makes things easier... I still don't see how to prove e.g. something like $\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{1\\1} = \pmatrix{x&1}\pmatrix{1\\y}$ or $\pmatrix{x&0} + \pmatrix{0&y} = \pmatrix{x&y}$

Comment: Okay, since this is getting long, I asked a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912960/matrix-multiplication-in-linear-categories-exercise-23-1. I hope you'll answer it!

Answer (score 2):

This answer seems to be exactly the same as Berci's except worse. But I'll write the idea using Lawvere's notation so that maybe it is more clear to someone using the book (like me) learning this for the first time.

If the map $$ A \times B \overset{\alpha_{AB}}{\to} A +B $$ denotes the inverse of the "identity matrix"

$$\begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} $$

then we have the following identities:

> $$ \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle 1_A, 0_{AB} \rangle = j_{A+B}^1 \,, \quad \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle  0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle = j_{A+B}^2 \,, \quad \begin{cases} 1_A \\ 0_{BA} \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} = \pi_{A \times B}^1 \,, \quad \begin{cases} 0_{AB} \\ 1_B \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} = \pi_{A \times B}^2 \,.$$

The proofs follow from the definition of $\alpha_{AB}$, namely:

$$ \alpha_{AB} \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases}  = 1_{A+B} \implies j_{A+B}^1 = \alpha_{AB} \circ \left( \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ j_{A+B}^1 \right) = \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle 1_A, 0_{AB} \rangle  $$

$$ \alpha_{AB} \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases}  = 1_{A+B} \implies j_{A+B}^2 = \alpha_{AB} \circ \left( \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ j_{A+B}^2 \right) = \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle  0_{BA} , 1_B \rangle  $$

$$ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} = 1_{A \times B} \implies \pi_{A \times B}^1 = \left( \pi_{A \times B}^1  \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} = \left(  \begin{cases} \pi_{A \times B}^1 \circ \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \pi_{A \times B}^1 \circ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} = \begin{cases} 1_A \\ 0_{BA} \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} $$

$$ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} = 1_{A \times B} \implies \pi_{A \times B}^2 = \left( \pi_{A \times B}^2  \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} = \left(  \begin{cases} \pi_{A \times B}^2 \circ \langle 1_A, 0_{AB}\rangle \\  \pi_{A \times B}^2 \circ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} = \begin{cases} 0_{AB} \\ 1_B \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} $$ $\triangle$

With that under our belt, the result is fairly straightforward:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1_A & f \\ 0_{BA} & 1_B \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1_A & g \\ 0_{BA} & 1_B \end{bmatrix} = \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , g \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , f \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} =: \begin{bmatrix} h_{AA} & h_{AB} \\ h_{BA} & h_{BB} \end{bmatrix}  \,.$$

Therefore we have that:

$$ h_{AA} = \left( \pi_{A+B}^1 \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , g \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ  \left(  \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , f \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ j_{A+B}^1 \right) = \begin{cases} 1_A \\ 0_{BA} \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle 1_A, f \rangle = \pi_{A\times B}^1 \circ \langle 1_A, f \rangle = 1_A $$

$$ h_{BA} = \left( \pi_{A+B}^1 \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , g \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ  \left(  \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , f \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ j_{A+B}^2 \right) = \begin{cases} 1_A \\ 0_{BA} \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle =\begin{array}{c} \pi_{A\times B}^1 \circ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \\ \begin{cases}1_A \\ 0_{BA} \end{cases} \circ j_{A+B}^2 \end{array} = 0_{BA} $$

$$ h_{BB} = \left( \pi_{A+B}^2 \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , g \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ  \left(  \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , f \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ j_{A+B}^2 \right) = \begin{cases} g \\ 1_{B} \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle = \begin{cases} g \\ 1_{B} \end{cases}  \circ j_{A+B}^2 = 1_B$$

We even get as a bonus an explicit form for $f+g$ (although to be honest I have not yet found this helpful for solving the subsequent Exercise 1, which is why I wound up on Math.SE in the first place):

$$f+g := h_{AB} = \left( \pi_{A+B}^2 \circ \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , g \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \right) \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ  \left(  \begin{cases} \langle 1_A , f \rangle \\ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_B \rangle \end{cases} \circ j_{A+B}^1 \right) = \begin{cases} g \\ 1_B \end{cases} \circ \alpha_{AB} \circ \langle 1_A, f \rangle \,. $$

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it's really helped.  A couple of small suggestions: (a) may be simpler to use the notation p_A rather than $\pi_{A \times B}^1$ and similarly for the other three projections/injections. (b) It helped a lot for me when I did this to refer to page 277 where Lawvere has the equation $f_{\mu \nu} = p_{\nu} f j_{\mu}$. (c) I think there's an errant $\pi_{A \times B}^1 \circ \langle 0_{BA}, 1_{B} \rangle $ in the penultimate line of your $h_{BA}$. I don't think it should be there.